# Python 3.5 can't decode Korean Won (currency) symbol?

Tags: python

```
a_string = 'à'.encode ('utf-8')
print (a_string)

b_string = '₩'.encode ('utf-8')
print (b_string)

a_bytes = a_string.decode ('utf-8')
print (a_bytes)

b_bytes = b_string.decode ('utf-8')   # This line gives error: Character maps to undefined
print (b_bytes)
```

Output is:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is this a Python 3.5 problem?

Output of:

```
import locale

print (locale.getdefaultlocale ())
```

is:

```
('en_US', 'cp1252')
```

Python version is 3.5.1

[EDIT]

This indeed turns out to be a Windows locale problem.
All works fine on Linux.

Comment: Works fine (Python 3.5.2, ubuntu 16.10): https://i.imgur.com/raQq0JP.png

Comment: I ran your script without problem on Python 3.5.2, what's your version?

Comment: can you post the output of `locale` into your question?

Comment: It's up to the locale on the terminal/console/editor you're using.

Comment: Your names are a bit confusing. `'₩'` is a string literal, if you encode it you get a `bytes` object, but you call that `b_string`, and if you decode that you get a `str` again, but you call that `b_bytes`.

Comment: @mata Very confusing! Editted accordingly.

Comment: @hansaplast: My Python version is 3.5.1

Comment: @Alfabravo: output of locale.getdefaultlocale () is ('en.US', 'cp1252')

Comment: [change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: Please do not post images for pure textual output. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal is set to the encoding `cp1252`. The symbols `à` and `₩` are not the supported characters.

Set your shell to e.g. utf-8 like this:

```
export LC_ALL=UTF-8
```

**Edit** Since you are using Windows see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)  how to change the encoding in Windows cmd

Comment: OP may use Windows which mostly use `CP1250` but doesn't have `export` and `LC_ALL`

Comment: I'm indeed on Windows, any solution for that? (other than switching to Linux).

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge try [change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: @furas: I changed the code page with chcp 65001, the error is gone but the output isn't printed correctly. Also tried the link you gave me (thanks) but unfortunately my registry (windows 8.0) doesn't have the indicated keys.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I don't use Windows so I can't help more. But put in question screen what you get. Maybe console uses font which doesn't have this char.

Comment: Thanks for all advice. It's indeed a Windows problem, works fine on Linux. I'll dive a little bit more in Windows code pages.